# Impossible to clone a repository on my Ubuntu Server - EC2

Tags: git, ubuntu, github

I installed an EC2 server on AWS, no issue there.
I install git and follow all the steps to be able to clone my projects (Private and Public).

This is what I received as error

```
 sudo git clone git@github.com:JulienHe/swap-lang.git
Cloning into 'swap-lang'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I follow a bunch of articles that try to solve my problem.
The weird part is the fact that I cant even clone Public Repository :/.

What is working

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
Agent pid 18879
```

```
ssh-add -l
2048 SHA256:bzMxy+mPI89uzNcwbkqlxCY8EfJhqoc/afuiNdUyL8Q /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
```

```
ssh -vvv git@github.com
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/ubuntu/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for github.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "github.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to github.com [52.69.186.44] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-dae25663
debug1: no match: babeld-dae25663
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from github.com
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-dss,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from github.com
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 52.69.186.44
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa (0x555e75ca3870), explicit, agent
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-dss>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: 
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SHA256:bzMxy+mPI89uzNcwbkqlxCY8EfJhqoc/afuiNdUyL8Q
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:bzMxy+mPI89uzNcwbkqlxCY8EfJhqoc/afuiNdUyL8Q
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to github.com ([52.69.186.44]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: callback start
debug1: Requesting authentication agent forwarding.
debug2: channel 0: request auth-agent-req@openssh.com confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AGENT_PID
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env SSH_CLIENT
debug3: Ignored env OLDPWD
debug3: Ignored env SSH_TTY
debug1: Sending env LC_ALL = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env MAIL
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env XDG_DATA_DIRS
debug3: Ignored env SSH_CONNECTION
debug1: Sending env LC_CTYPE = UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env LESSOPEN
debug3: Ignored env XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
debug3: Ignored env LESSCLOSE
debug3: Ignored env _
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 32000 rmax 35000
debug3: receive packet: type 100
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 100 id 0
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 90
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 96
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf_empty delayed efd 7/(90)
Hi JulienHe! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
debug2: channel 0: written 90 to efd 7
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug2: channel 0: close_read
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug3: send packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r43 i3/0 o3/0 fd -1/-1 cc -1)

debug3: send packet: type 1
Connection to github.com closed.
Transferred: sent 3100, received 2248 bytes, in 0.3 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 9524.7, received 6907.0
debug1: Exit status 1
```

I expect that I can clone things on my server.

I hope someone knows where I should look around!
Thanks!!!

Comment: Have you already put the keys from the EC2 server to the git?

Comment: Yes @Pacifist, the content of my key id_rsa.pub is on my github ssh key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo` is the culprit of the problem. It changes the current user from `JulienHe` to `root` and user `root` doesn't have access to `JulienHe`'s ssh agent and keys. Try `sudo ssh -Tv git@github.com`.

Never use `sudo` when you don't really need it for administrative tasks.